# При открытии Корзины в modal-body вместо таблицы с товарами появляется главная страница сайта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, корзина, modal

После нажатия кнопки "В корзину" открывается окно modal. C header и с footer все хорошо, а вот в modal-body показывается полностью страница.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

несколько раз проверял код, но ошибку так и не нашел.

код в main.js:

```js
function showCart(cart) {

    $('#cart .modal-body').html(cart);
    $('#cart').modal();
}
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        qty = $('#qty').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cart/add',
        data: {id: id, qty: qty},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(res){
            if(!res)
                {alert('Ошибка!');}
            showCart(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});
```

код в main.php:

```
<?php
\yii\bootstrap\Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2>Корзина</h2>',
    'id' => 'cart',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'footer' => '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Продолжить покупки</button>
        <a href="' . \yii\helpers\Url::to(['cart/view']) . '" class="btn btn-success">Оформить заказ</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="clearCart()">Очистить корзину</button>'
]);

\yii\bootstrap\Modal::end();
?>
```

при чем, если в открытом окне снова нажать на "в корзину", откроется новое окно в браузере с нужной таблицей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но без стилей...

Comment: что у вас по ссылке `/cart/add` рендерится, то и показалось внутри

Comment: @teran рендерится у меня как раз 'cart-modal'
'        $this->layout = false;
        return $this->render('cart-modal', compact('session'));'

Comment: ну вы же не будете отрицать, что сгенерированный `res` от `cart/add` передается в функцию `showCart` и устанавливается в качестве боди окна с помощью `html()` ?

Comment: @teran, я все равно не понимаю...

Comment: @teran ,вот мой код для шоукарт:

'function showCart(cart) {

    $('#cart .modal-body').html(cart);
    $('#cart').modal();
}
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        qty = $('#qty').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cart/add',
        data: {id: id, qty: qty},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(res){
            if(!res)
                {alert('Ошибка!');}
            showCart(res);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
    });
});'

Comment: это у вас в вопросе уже приведено. лучше дополните, что у вас в пхп-коде на этот случай вызывается